# Set tsconfig to ignore "Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'bar'." but only for a specific variable

Tags: typescript, lint, tslint, tsconfig

I have an object `foo` that is used all around the codebase and need to access the property `bar` from it. However, due to specific circumstances ts thinks that property does not exist on it, even though it in fact does. So I am getting the redline with this message all over the place:

> Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'bar'

In my ts-config file, I would like to set it to ignore all these errors, but ONLY for the `foo` variable.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in `tsconfig`, there is no such setting. You can do one of several things.

Use a type assertion to `any`. Using this all property accesses are allowed:

```
(bar as any).foo
```

Another option is to just suppress the error. You can use `@ts-ignore` to suppress ALL errors for the next line

```
//@ts-ignore
bar.foo // no error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=20&pln=4&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4wLwwN4F8BQPFIB0AZiCDAPQUwCmSSISeVAAlBALQCWA5mIzXzISZStX616jIA)

**Note**: You might be better off finding the reason for the error, or augmenting the type or charging the type of the variable to something that incudes `foo` but without more details it is difficult to propose a solution.

Comment: Guess that is what I was trying to avoid because it's all over the place. But if it can't be done, then it can't be done.
Thanks for the help!